# Center favicon in background CSS

Tags: css, favicon

I am currently trying to center favicons in this circular background so it can change color on hover. I am struggling a little bit to center it, though. I tried `text-align: center` but that was no use. Not very up to speed with CSS. What should I be doing instead?

https://codepen.io/teecp/pen/gOYRwbO

Comment: A favicon is the little icon you see at the top of a browser tab. I think you're just referring to regular icons.

Comment: Please include all relevant code **in the question itself**. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you by not making us go off site to find critical information.

Comment: what background  you want to change on hover?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is to set fixed `height` and `width` on the parent element. Then set the icon's dimensions the same with a line height that measures its height.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #7b68ee;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidebar a {
  position: relative;
  left: 20%;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 90px;
  width: 20%;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* Added the properties below */
  height: 50px; 
  width: 50px;
  
}

main .sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-left: 85px;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s;
}

.sidebar .fas:hover {
  background: #ffffff1a;
  border-radius: 90px;
}

.sidebar-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

/* Added the block below */
.fa, .far, .fas {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
    line-height: 50px!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b61e574d7a.js"></script>

<div class="sidebar">
  <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-chess-queen"></i></a>
  

<div id="main">
  hello
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove padding, add width, height and line-height.

```
.sidebar a {
      position: relative;
      left: 20%;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      line-height: 55px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 25px;
      background: red;
      border-radius: 90px;
      color: #ffffff;
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```